# Organize Models in subdirectories CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

we are using subdirectories in our projects no separete views and controllers but in models we didn’t learn yet. Recently I’ve found this https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/60451 and actually routes and plugins we are already using, we just want to separete our models like this:

```
Model
-Entity
–Financial
—Money.php
-Table
–Financial
—MoneyTable.php
```

I’ve tryed put like this then controller is not able to find his model. How can I do to organize it, and make it work?

Things that we've tried:
Use `$this->setAlias('TableModel');`
Call in controller:

```
$this->TableModel = $this->loadModel('Subfolder/TableModel');
```

didn't work for SQL build, and other classes.

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP uses the `TableRegister` to load models. That class can be configured to use a class that implements the `LocatorInterface`, and CakePHP uses the `TableLocator` as the default.

The only thing you can do is configure your own `LocatorInterface` instance in your `bootstrap.php`. You would have to create your `MyTableLocator` and have it change the `className` for tables to point to subdirectories. What rules for this class name rewritting are used is purely up to you.

**bootstrap.php**:

```
TableRegister::setTableLocator(new MyTableLocator());
```

**MyTableLocator.php**:

```
class MyTableLocator extends TableLocator {
    protected function _getClassName($alias, array $options = [])
    {
       if($alias === 'Subfolder/TableModel') {
           return TableModel::class;
       }
       return parent::_getClassName($alias, $options);
    }
}
```

The above isn't working code.

I'm just demonstrating what the function is you need to override, and that you need logic in place to return a different class name.

You can check if the `$alias` contains the `/` character, and if so. Return a class name by extracting the subfolder name from the `$alias`. Take a look at the `TableLocator` to see how it's using the `App::className` function.